# Regex replace issue with question mark

Tags: regex

I've the below text in my file

```
    <td class="toc-subitem-num"></td>
    <td class="toc-title">Section 170 Text</td>
    <td class="toc-subitem-num"></td>
    <td class="toc-title">
       <span class="font-style-italic">Section 170A Text</span>
    </td>
```

I want to capture the `Section <number>` part and I'm using the below regex to do so.

```
<td class="toc-subitem-num"></td>[\r\s\n]*<td class="toc-title">([\r\s\n]*<span class=\"font-style-italic\">)?Section ([0-9]+)([A-Z]+)?
```

The search is working fine, But in the replace I want this number to come in the first tag, The replace that I use is as below.

```
<td class="toc-subitem-num">Section $1$2$3</td><td class="toc-title">
```

**My current o/p:**

```
<td class="toc-subitem-num">Section 170</td><td class="toc-title"> Text</td>
 <td class="toc-subitem-num">Section 
   <span class="font-style-italic">170A</td><td class="toc-title"> Text</span>
```

**Expected O/p:**

```
<td class="toc-subitem-num">Section 170</td><td class="toc-title"> Text</td>
     <td class="toc-subitem-num">Section 170A</td>
       <td class="toc-title"><span class="font-style-italic"> Text</span>
```

Please let me know how CAn I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this regex for use in javascript?

Comment: @kcrk yes, it is for Js.

Comment: I see the problem with this: https://regex101.com/r/fS9lC3/1

Comment: Hi @kcrk, I'm able to match the required content, unable to know how do I replace the same

Comment: Posted anser below

Comment: Did the answer work? @user3872094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix this you need to make sure the capturing groups are in order:

```
/<td class="toc-subitem-num"><\/td>[\s]*<td class="toc-title">[\s]*(<span class=\"font-style-italic\">)?(Section [\d]+[A-Z]*)? ([\w ]+)(<\/span>\s+)?(<\/td>)/gi
```

See functional verison in action here: https://regex101.com/r/fS9lC3/3

Capturing groups 2 and 3 now always return what you want.

```
<td class="toc-subitem-num">$2</td><td class="toc-title">$1$3$4</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 capture groups and move the 3th

```
str = str.replace(/(<td class="toc-subitem-num">)(<\/td>\s*<td class="toc-title">\s*(?:<span class="font-style-italic">)?)(Section\s*[0-9]+[A-Z]*)\s*/g, "$1$3$2");
```